# Are notices harm to a website and its performance

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should PHP 'Notices' be reported and fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929996/should-php-notices-be-reported-and-fixed)

Till date i was ignoring the php notices, thinking that we will disable it when website is live. Now  a scenario has occurred where in clients have enabled logging of the notices also to the log and because of this the log size was growing enormously. I was always thinking that production environment will come with notices logging disabled. So we had to sit and remove each of these notices. So wanted to know will these notices cause any harm to website. Or should we take it as developers buggy code ?

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929996/should-php-notices-be-reported-and-fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good developers  need to solve such issues.
Some time such issues may generate some security issues like sql injection.
Some hackers may damage your database with the help of sql injection.